# Прошу помогите с sql запросом для базы данных chinook.db

Tags: sql, база-данных, sqlite

Суть запроса: *Для каждого альбома определить все жанры песен, которые в нём есть и количество песен по каждому жанру (формат вывода: альбом, жанр, количество). Выводить только те альбомы, где жанров больше одного.*

Ссылка на сайт с бд: https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-sample-database/

Структура chinook.db:[image: chinook.db]

Я пробовал сделать разные sql запросы по типу:

```
SELECT
    a.Title AS AlbumTitle,
    g.Name AS Genre,
    COUNT(t.TrackId) AS NumberOfTracks
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM albums
    WHERE albumid IN (
        SELECT albumid
        FROM tracks
        GROUP BY albumid
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT genreid) > 1
    )
) a
JOIN tracks t ON a.albumid = t.albumid
JOIN genres g ON t.genreid = g.genreid;
```

или

```
SELECT
    a.Title AS AlbumTitle,
    g.Name AS Genre,
    COUNT(t.TrackId) AS NumberOfTracks
FROM
    Albums a
JOIN
    Tracks t ON a.AlbumId = t.AlbumId
JOIN
    Genres g ON t.GenreId = g.GenreId
GROUP BY
    AlbumTitle, Genre
HAVING COUNT(t.TrackId) > 1
ORDER BY
    Genre;
```

но ни один из этих запросов не выводит того, что требуется. Я не могу понять что не так ведь я задаю условие для количества жанров больше одного.

**Необходимый результат это вывод таблицы с альбомами где жанров больше одного.**

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос сами таблицы и данные в них + необходимый результат выборки. Без этой информации сложно угадать нужный ответ

Comment: добавил информацию

Answer (score 0):

Должно получиться вот таким запросом:

```
select a.title, g.name, count(*)
from albums a
join tracs t on a.albumid = t.albumid
join genres g on t.genreid = g.genreid
group by a.title, g.name
having count(*) > 1
```

Не имея доступа к данным в БД, сделал [аналог в песочнице](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cHSv5CfqfqStGR467FAxAu/0)

Comment: к сожалению выводит не то, что требуется, могу прикрепить ссылку на гитхаб в котором находиться файл с бд и "SQL3" в котором есть задание №4 по которому у меня вопрос, если это чем-нибудь поможет: [https://github.com/ShadowGhosto/SQL]